# Is a group scheme determined by its category of representations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, representable-functors, tannakian-category

More precisely, let $G$ be an affine group scheme over a field $k$, $Rep_k(G)$ be the category of finite dimensional representations of G, and $\omega_0$ be the forgetful functor from $Rep_k(G)$ to the category of vector spaces over $k$. With the usual notation in the theory of Tannakian categories, is the natural map $G\longrightarrow \underline{\text{Aut}}^{\otimes} (\omega_0)$ an isomorphism of group schemes over $k$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, see Deligne–Milne, "Tannakian Categories", Proposition 2.8, which says precisely this.  (It doesn't matter what kind of field $k$ is, but many of the more specific recognition theorems, such as that for reductivity, do.)

I feel like I must be misunderstanding, since I understood that to *be* the theory of Tannakian categories at its most basic.

Answer (score 1):

N̶o̶.̶ (YES, the answer above is correct.) The following example shows we cannot drop that condition:  Work out the example of $G = E$ an elliptic curve/$k$. (The Rep category is severely degenerate in this case.)

[Edited. Some how at that late hour I completely missed the word 'affine' in the OP. Indeed, if the group is affine then his question is answered by the celebrated Tannaka theorems. I'll leave the info here though as it's nice to have examples of what fails.]

Not all is lost though. A more general type of phenomena you may be interested in is that if you start with $T = $Coh($Y$) (coherent sheaves) than you can actually construct a stack $X$ which behaves as $X(S) =$ {fiber functors $T \to S$-mod}, where $S$ is a $k$-algebra.

If your scheme $Y$ was nice enough, then $X$ will actually be $Y$. (If I recall correctly, separatedness is critical.)

In fact this is what you are doing in the well known affine group reconstruction case as well: Under the hood you are using $BG$. This has only one point and the uniqueness of the fiber functor reflects this.

Comment: $E$ is not affine :P

Comment: In fact there is something serious and unknown to me here. Let us look at it this way: when your "standard cogenerator" does not work on some particular object you use instead of maps to this cogenerator sections of bundles with fibre the cogenerator. E. g. there are not enough functions on projective varieties, so you use sections of line bundles on them instead. Now switch on the group structure; you have a single object groupoid in schemes with not enough functors to $\text{Vect}$. Following the above principle one should use some kind of $\text{Vect}$-bundles over the groupoid?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Here is a counterexample, suggesting that it is hopeless to reconstruct $BE$ from the category of sheaves: $\mathbb P^1$ and $E$ are complete, so that GAGA applies to their categories of coherent sheaves. If you could reconstruct $BE$ from the category of sheaves on $E$, that would suggest that you could describe maps $\mathbb P^1\to BE$ in terms of sheaves. But there are more analytic maps (Hopf surfaces) than algebraic. The total spaces aren't projective, but $\mathbb P^1$ and $E$ are. [Lurie](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412266) isolates this as uniquely bad.

Comment: @BenWieland Sorry this is way above my level, so what follows may be completely senseless, but I rather had in mind some kind of "meromorphic representations" of $E$ (as a group). Something like a system of line bundles $(L_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ on $E$ and sections $s_{ij}$ of $L_i^*\otimes L_j$, with $s_{ij}(xy)=\sum_ks_{ik}(x)s_{kj}(y)$, where the latter sum is understood as a convolution of sections of $(L_i^*\otimes L_k)\boxtimes(L_k^*\otimes L_j)$...

Comment: Haha, I somehow did not notice the question asked for `affine'! Yes of course the affine case is the celebrated theorem.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Conceptually, you should consider the 2-category of representations of $E$ on (sufficiently good) abelian categories over $R$ (here $R$ is the base ring which I will assume $=\mathbb C$ for fun). For example, a representation of $E$ on $Vect_{\mathbb C}$ is the same as a representation of cogroup $QCoh(E)$ on $Vect_{\mathbb C}$ ($QCoh(E)$ has obvious multiplication and inherits comultiplication from $E$), which is the same as a line bundle on $E$. Thus linear 2-representations of $E$ correspond to points on the dual elliptic curve.

Comment: (cont...) A fibre functor should map this 2-category of representations to the 2-category of $\mathbb C$-abelian categories. Invertible representations defined above will map to invertible categories, which for $R = \mathbb C$ are all isomorphic to $Vect_{\mathbb C}$, an isomorphism defined by a line over $\mathbb C$. Thus a fiber functor gives a point on the double dual curve, i.e. on $E$. An automorphism of fiber functor also corresponds to a point on double dual, thus we reconstruct $E$ tannakially. The details are complicated, you should post a question if you are interested.

Comment: @Anton Thank you, it is much more solid than what I would ever imagine! And you are right, I will try to formulate a separate question.

Comment: @Anton Yes, thank you. This picture is quite nice. I handn't attempted to think about that aspect 2-categorically.